# ACF Taxonomy Order

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, taxonomy

I've created a ACF taxonomy field that selects Woocommerce product categories. It has a multi select appearance and I want to order the taxonomies in the multi select order.

It is working, but only displaying in alphabetical order.
I'm missing something, but can't find the solution.

This is the code i'm using:

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );
            ?>

            <?php if( $terms ): 
                ?>
                <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
                <div class="col order-">
                    <div class="card h-100 pe-auto">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo $term->name; ?></h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="category-img">
                            <?php $thumb_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id' );
                                    $image = wp_get_attachment_url(  $thumb_id ); ?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" class="" alt="...">
                        </div>
                        <?php if( $term->description ): ?>
                        <div class="card-img-overlay d-flex">
                            <div class="card-text">
                                <p class=""><?php echo $term->description; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <a class="stretched-link " href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->term_id ); ?>"></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use wp_get_object_terms() function.

```
$terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_cat', ['orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC'])
```

Reference possible values of orderBy and order at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_term_query/__construct/

However, this function doesn't apply cache. If you want to apply cache, you can consider writing a custom function, like below:

```
function get_the_terms_by_order( $post, $taxonomy, $orderBy = 'name', $order = 'ASC') {
    $post = get_post( $post );

    if ( ! $post ) {
        return false;
    }

    $terms = get_object_term_cache( $post->ID, $taxonomy );

    if ( false === $terms ) {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, ['orderBy' => $orderBy, 'order' => $order] );
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {
            $term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );
            wp_cache_add( $post->ID, $term_ids, $taxonomy . '_relationships' );
        }
    }

    if ( empty( $terms ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    return $terms;
}
```

Then:

```
$terms = get_the_terms_by_order( $post, $taxonomy, 'name', 'DESC');
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I can now change the order, but not to the drag and drop multi-select order.

Comment: It's another case, right? Can you give more information?